# Multi-core programming

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a 6-core setup (intel xeon) with hyperthreading disabled running on Ubuntu.
I work on a software that increases the number of pthreads launched. When I increase my number of threads from say 3 to 6, I find that my CPU utilization by running the top command always remains around 290%. I am assuming that this means 3 out of 6 cores are being utilized. This is pretty confusing as I would expect all the cores to be utilized. I have checked the program's core affinity and it shows that its affine to all cores. Can anyone provide me with some hints or suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) your scheduler. 2) your other threads are idle. check `top -H`. 3) try pinning your threads to specific cores `pthread_setaffinity`.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing a thing about your program. Are you sure it is cpu-bound and threads are not waiting for other resources like I/O?